# What do I need "normal" functions for when I can write everything in main()?

Tags: c++

At the moment I'm only writing all the code in

```
main()
```

and that works quite well, so why do I need other "normal" functions?  I ask that because I have noticed that it is better. But why? Since I have never really dealt with functions, I would be very happy over explanations how a function works. Thanks in advance for the answers.

I understand a "normal" function so:

```
int firstFunction()
{
  // text like cout << example;
}

int main()
{
  firstFunction();
}
```

Comment: At work an average program for me is over 50 thousand lines of code. Putting that all in 1 function would be ridiculous.

Comment: Easier to manage. Easier to read. Repeated tasks in function instead of duplicating. Etc.

Comment: What is a "normal" function?

Comment: modularization...

Comment: It works for small and simple programs. As soon as you start a somewhat more sophisticated project, that simply won't do any more, for multiple reasons, some of them already mentioned by other comments. I'd add the one I find most important: separation of concerns. A function can take responsibility of one very specific task, while not having to know or concern itself with the greater context. This makes for easy to read, easy to assemble and also re-usable code.

Comment: I assume you are also not using OOP at all.

Comment: No, I don't use OOP

Comment: Easier to test too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the simplest of programs, having everything in `main()` is fine. But as soon as your program becomes somewhat more complex, your code will quickly become a nightmare to work with.

With functions, your code will ...

- ... be easier to read
- ... be easier to understand
- ... be easier to maintain
- ... be easier to distribute
- ... be easier to reuse
- ... be easier to test
- ... be easier to work on as a team
- ... have less code duplication
- ... have proper separation of concerns

A great function should ...

- ... only concern itself with a single task
- ... be as context-independent as possible
- ... have a name that clearly communicates what it does
- ... have a description that explains its contract, input and output

---

The best advice I can give to any beginner programmer is to break any problem down into smaller problems, then solve those one by one. Functions enable you to put this approach into code.

If you're still not convinced, think about this: whatever your program does, your code in `main()` is certainly calling functions, probably from the standard library. Things like `printf()`. Isn't that convenient? Imagine the authors had not used functions, how would you access that code?

The [Wikipedia article on functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subroutine#Advantages) also has a list of advantages.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously anyone would ask why would they need to define other function(s) except the main. But remember, it lets programmer reduce the lines of code from being repeated. Suppose you're calculating or performing something large which is used in overall program. So, you won't like to repeat the same code time and again. There you need to use the function.

Although it's just a simple explanation of advantage of using functions in a program. But in cases of building a simple program (not a project), perhaps you don't need any functions for sake of simplicity and it's fine too. But it's a good programming practice to write separated code in functions to make them more readable in case it's enough larger to maintain.

You may learn about functions on many sites by just searching about them. You'll get to know more (such as function overloading which is really helpful).

Comment: Thanks for answering "domsson" and "LinuX Man", now I finally understand the help of functions.

Comment: How do you mean this?

Comment: @Jeroen click the checkmark Icon on the answer that was most helpful. This way, your question will be marked as solved.